# Cannot find function in different directory but under the same directory

Tags: go

I have only one package `main`, but I am building multiple binaries:

```
--cmd
   --program1 
     --main.go
   --program2
     --main.go
--xxx.go
--yyy.go
--zzz.go
```

I want to call function in `xxx.go` in `program1/main.go`. The complier says `undeclared name:`.

I don't think I should import the function because all of them are under the same package `main`.

Comment: Different package path = different package, regardless of the package's name. Also main packages are not intended to be imported, if you need to declare the function in a package separate from main, then do not name that new package main as well, you'll just encounter problems.

Comment: Only the adjacent files form a package, files in a different directory (be it nested or not, does not matter) is a separated independent package.

Comment: Go works on packages, not on files (this is not 100.0% exact, but it is the most helpful way to think about such things). You thus do not call functions from xxx.go but from the package of which xxx.go is part of. You also do not import functions, you import packages. Each and every package you want to use you _must_ import. It does not matter where on the filesystem the package source is stored: You want to use package --> you must import it. You clearly have three packages, located in cmd, cmd/program1 and cmd/program2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do what you want, you need to put the files xxx.go, yyy.go and zzz.go into an internal package.

This is the directory layout you should have:

```
--cmd
   --program1 
     --main.go
   --program2
     --main.go
--internal
   --shared
      --xxx.go
      --yyy.go
      --zzz.go
```

In the files xxx.go, yyy.go, and zzz.go, you should have `package shared` at the beginning of the file.

In the files main.go, you should have `import "../../internal/shared"`. If you have a go.mod file with a fully qualified module name (e.g. github.com/me/project), you then can have `import "github.com/me/project/internal/shared"`.

Once you have this, you may call the exported functions of the shared package, thus from the xxx.go file, from the program’s main file. Note that a function is exported when the first letter of the function name is an uppercase letter.